# Wikiprep utility. Unable to Build Splitwiki

Tags: c++, c, makefile, wikipedia, dbpedia

I am trying to build the Wikiprep utility on my system. While I have built the utility, I am unable to build the Splitwiki utility. The make install instruction is

```
splitwiki: splitwiki.c 
              gcc -Wall -O2 -lz -o $@ $<
```

I get the following error messages upon execution:

```
/tmp/ccXeAIs1.o: In function `split':
splitwiki.c:(.text+0xac): undefined reference to `gzputs'
splitwiki.c:(.text+0xe3): undefined reference to `gzputs'
/tmp/ccXeAIs1.o: In function `main':
splitwiki.c:(.text.startup+0xab): undefined reference to `gzopen'
splitwiki.c:(.text.startup+0x10c): undefined reference to `gzclose'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [splitwiki] Error 1
```

I somehow have my gut saying I am missing some other packages, although I am not sure about it.
Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

gzputs() is part of zlib. You're probably not linking against zlib.

At the moment I'm wondering, how you're building splitwiki. I'd have expected it being build with 'make && make install' when building wikiprep. In my case it isn't. Can you give te commandline you're using to build splitwiki and all the output?

**Update**: The following works for me:

```
 $ cd tools/splitwiki
 $ make splitwiki LOADLIBES=-lz
 cc     splitwiki.c -lz  -o splitwiki    # this is make output
 $
```

Explanation: I could not find any part of the Makefile handling or any part of the README explainigg or directing how to build *splitwiki*. My assumption is, that one simply needs to do it manually and that's the way you tried it todo. The thing you probably have been missing was '-lz' (link against zlib). You could have used

```
 cc splitwiki.c -lz -o splitwiki
```

directly. Using make is only my way to invoke the compiler :-).

*Update 2*: Sorry, yesterday I seem to have missed the part of the question saying "the make install instruction is". So you seem to have gotten the -lz switch. NOrmally I'd say install zlib, but I'm a bit confused that you don't get '/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz' as error message. Are you sure you're giving all the log output relating to the compilation of splitwiki?

Comment: Thanks. I checked out from the master at https://github.com/avian2/wikiprep.git which has a Makefile for the splitwiki utility. Unfortunately my AWS instance was deleted yesterday. Will setup the code running on my system at home and update you with the messages I am getting in 12 hours.